# Full-proof way to check if PWA was opened from the Android app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I need to check if my PWA was opened from the Android app (ONLY the Android app, this check should return false if the PWA was opened directly via PWA installation) in order to show the Play Store payments dialog, rather than Stripe Billing (the default on web).

Based on previous answers to this question, I'm checking BOTH the referrer AND via a query param, then setting the sessionStorage if either one checks out:

```
  if (
    // Android is supposed to set this when opening TWA from app
    document.referrer.includes('android-app://${MY_APP_ID}') ||
    // ...but it's not always reliable, so add this check, which we set
    // manually when building the Android shell.
    searchParams.get('from') === 'android_app'
  ) {
    // Set session storage so that this flag persists across page reloads when
    // in the app.
    sessionStorage.setItem(ANDROID_APP_KEY, 'true');
  }
```

This works fine the first time the app is opened. However, I've noticed that when the app is exited for some time, and then resumed, this check does not work all the time - although I haven't been able to repro reliably.

Has anyone encountered this? Is there a foolproof way to ensure the PWA was opened from my Android app? I need the Play Store payments dialog to always open in the Android app to stay compliant with Play Store payments policies..